# Frame navigation with RenderTransform

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to implement simple frame application in WPF which will open few websites like google, yahoo..
I have a frame like this:

```
    <Frame x:Name="framenew" Content="Frame" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="439,327,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Frame.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-27.751"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Frame.RenderTransform>
```

I am trying to load www.google.com when my application gets launched.

`frame1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));`

But instead of honoring above mentioned angle (for `RotateTransform`), it defaults the angle to 0 and frame becomes the way it was before rotating.

Can some one explain what is it I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It don't work because internally it instanciates a WebBrowser control. But WebBrowser is not a native WPF control its an hwnd host. And it can't be trasformed except with translate transform. There is no solution to this problem using standard WPF but you can try using Awesomium .Net wrapper.